# tail all log files in a directory | exclude zipped files

Tags: linux, log-files, tail, exclude

Im trying to find the right command to tail a bunch of log files whilst excluding the zipped files in a set directory. The log files are being zipped as they become oversized.

At the moment Im using:

```
tail -f /var/logs/myLog*
```

Which works fine, but it will also tail the .gz files which are a garbled mess. I need to tail only files without this extension.

Comment: Do file names before the gzip have anything else in common - file ending, number of periods in the name, or something else?

Comment: Nothing that they dont share with the zipped versions. The logs are simply nameOfLog with no extension and the zipped files are nameOfLog.gz.... unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the filenames have anything else in common - e.g. length of name, number of periods in name, name ending... you can simply adjust your glob.

If not, there are some other ways:

```
tail -f `ls -l /var/logs/myLog* |grep -v .gz$`
```

or, using xargs:

```
ls /var/logs/myLog* | grep -v .gz$ | xargs tail -f
```

Comment: tail -f `ls -l /var/logs/myLog* |grep -v .gz$` works straight away! Awesome. Could you expand on the $ at the end of the grep? I understand -v to invert the selection but why the $?

Comment: A dollar sign anchors a search to the end of a string. In other words, pass through files with gz anywhere in the name

Answer (score 6):

Usually `tail -f /var/logs/myLog*log` will work. However, if the end of the filenames is unpredictable, and really the only way is to exclude files ending in `.gz`, it becomes more complicated. One possibility is this:

```
ls /var/logs/myLog* | grep -v .gz$ | xargs tail -f
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Although when I run it I get a list of the correct files (so it is finding them properly!) but with the errors "Cannot open [file] for reading: No such file or directory". Obviously the file exists, its finding it itself! I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @JackalopeZero -  If the log files don't end in the letter z, in bash you can ignore files ending in z (like .gz) with: `tail *[^z]`

Comment: @JackalopeZero - I can't tell. Do the filenames have spaces or any other strange characters? Is it possible that `ls` and/or `grep` insert any color codes? (You can try to add `--color=never` both to `ls` and to `grep`.) These are wild guesses though - I can't tell you if I don't see it. Maybe if you copy and paste the exact messages we could get a clue.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, if the `extendedglob` option is set (it is by default), you can negate a glob pattern by wrapping it in parentheses and prepending a bang (`!`). For example, `!(*.gz)` matches all items whose names don't end with `.gz`. See the `Pathname Expansion` subsection in the `EXPANSION` section in the `bash` manual page for more information.

In `zsh`, if the `extglob` option is set (it is *not*, by default), you can negate a glob pattern by prepending a caret (`^`). For example, `^*.gz` matches all items whose names don't end with `.gz`. See the `FILENAME GENERATION` section in the `zshexpn` manual page for more information.

Note that in general, if you want to use `ls` with a glob pattern, you should specify `-d`. This is because the shell expands the glob pattern into a list of matching names, passing each one to `ls` as a separate argument. If you don't use `-d`, `ls` will list the *contents* of any directories whose names it's given.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `-n` option to specify that you don't want the "old" ones:

```
tail -f -n 0 /var/log/*
```

or

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/*
```

Comment: That's a clever one actually ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following line:

```
file /var/log/* | grep "ASCII text" | cut -d ":" -f 1 | xargs tail -f
```